# Auto start apps not starting on scheduled boot

Tags: macos, imac, startup

I'm not really sure if I'm missing something here, but isn't the idea behind the auto boot and auto shutdown that the mac is ready to work with in the morning when starting to work?

For me that's not quite working.

My Mac starts every morning at 9, I'm in the office at 10 and the Mac is ready to enter my password.

But as soon as I do that, all the auto start apps start opening. Outlook is the biggest problem here, because the software is so insane bad, that it takes ages to start with a big mailbox.
I then have to wait something like 10 minutes to actually start working normally. Or even open a website. Not even the settings app is responding for some minutes.

How can I enable to start all those apps already with my auto boot, so I just enter my password, and everything is already running?

I thought this is the idea with autostart?

In no other case than the morning boot my Mac is as slow like this. When everything is running and had it's time to start correctly, it is working super snappy and fast.

My system:
macOS Big Sur 11.5.2
iMac 27" 2019
3 GHz 6 Core i5
40 GB Ram

I only have one administrator account on this machine and the guest is disabled. So there is no other choice to select which user should be loaded.

Comment: First I would look at controlling the mailbox: archive, file or delete...

Comment: Fair point, but it's one big exchange mailbox for everybody in our company. I already "archived it down" from 30 GB to 12 GB

Comment: 'autostarts' are 'Login Items'… there's a rather unfortunate hint in the title - they'll start at login. I don't know a way round that short of auto-logging in, which would be a security concern in a location you will not be present when it happens.

Comment: Asking why you shut down the machine every night, vs putting it to sleep?

Comment: @MarcWilson - yup, that would be the 'simplest' fix ;))

Comment: I do so to clear ram and don't carry any "problems" or slowdowns to the next day. I now reduced it to once a week

Comment: 'clear RAM' … errmmm… you don't need to do that.

Comment: Yeah could be. But I feel like when the mac is running for weeks without a restart and only standby, it gets slower and slower. So a clean reboot fixes that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found this option in the settings by changing my start options. So far it's working as I wanted it.

Go to `Users & Groups` and select `Login Options` there you can select a user for automatic login.

[image: Screenshot of settings]

Comment: Yup, as in my first comment above. If it's not a security concern, then it will work just fine. :)

Comment: No, not really. I still had to enter my password to login.

Comment: You did - but now it will start up & login automatically… before you get to work. By the time you get there it may have had time to lock again - during which time those processes would continue, but there would be a period it's unlocked & unattended. That was my initial concern. I do it myself here at home, because I don't consider it so much of a risk.

Comment: Good point. Didn't thought about it that way. But no, that's no concern because everything is stored on our server anyway.